# Fastest way to find sum of any rectangle in matrix

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I have a m x n matrix and want to be able to calculate sums of arbitrary rectangular submatrices. This will happen several times for the given matrix. What data structure should I use?

For example I want to find sum of rectangle in matrix

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
```

Sum is 68.

What I'll do is accumulating  it row by row:

```
1   2   3   4
6   8   10  12
15  18  21  24
28  32  36  40
```

And then, if I want to find sum of the matrix I just accumulate  **28,32,36,40 = 136**. Only four operation instead of 15.
If I want to find sum of second and third row, I just accumulate **15,18,21,24** and subtract **1, 2, 3, 4.** = 6+8+10+12+15+18+21+24 = **68**.
But in this case I can use another matrix, accumulating this one by columns:

```
1   3   6   10
5   11  18  26
9   19  30  42
13  27  42  58
```

and in this case I just sum **26** and **42** = **68**. Only 2 operation instead of 8.  For wider sub-matrix is is efficient to use second method and matrix, for higher - first one. Can I somehow split merge this to methods to one matrix?

So I just sum to corner and subtract another two?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're nearly there with your method. The solution is to use a summed area table (aka Integral Image):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table

The key idea is you do one pass through your matrix and accumulate such that "the value at any point (x, y) in the summed area table is just the sum of all the pixels above and to the left of (x, y), inclusive.".

Then you can compute the sum inside any rectangle in constant time with four lookups.

Comment: This is advantageous, if *several* sum queries run over all or part of the matrix.

Comment: In my case it is significant big number of sums

Comment: Is there  fast Java implementation? If I do this brute force => recursively - it is very slow.

Comment: Do it iteratively with two loops, not recursively. You can also re-use your existing functions: `summed_table = accumulate_rows(accumulate_columns(matrix))`

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just add them using For loops?

```
int total = 0;
for(int i = startRow; i = endRow; i++)
{
    for(int j = startColumn; j = endColumn; j++)
    {
        total += array[i][j];
    }
}
```

Where your subarray ("rectangle") would go from startRow to endRow (width) and startColumn to endColumn (height).

Comment: What if I want to find sums of 100 sub-matrices in matrix NxN with N = 1000?

Comment: Then you take the above code and put it in a function called
     SumSubarray(int startRow, int endRow, int startCol, int endCol) 

and call that for each sub-matrix, then add your results.

Comment: @JohnDow For a one time calculation Cyber is right. If you want to optimize for multiple sub-sums mention it in your question (I don't see it there)

Comment: Hm, I see it in the headline now.